# RC snubber across mosfet or diode with ferrite bead

Tags: snubber, emi-filtering

I already designed a RC snubber across a mosfet and diode successfully .

Reading through some whitepapers , I have seen the addition of a ferrite bead in series with RC snubber.

Do you recommend it or I should stick to RC snubbers only ? (the goal is to reduce noise/emi to lowest possible levels)

Adding link to ferrite bead addition (fig 4) https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Optimizing_CoolMOSCE_based_power_supplies_for_EMI-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462584d1d4a01584ee2e19d0376

Comment: Reducing noise to lowest possible level usually means driving the MOSFET slowly and much more inefficiently. Are you prepared to do this or are you more likely to be reasonable and have manageable aims and also link to the white papers that talk about the ferrite beads.

Comment: On mosfet we have a R on the gate and a Diode for turn off (+ ferrite bead_..so yes the turn on will be slower. Fig4 on this link shows the ferite bead. https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Optimizing_CoolMOSCE_based_power_supplies_for_EMI-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462584d1d4a01584ee2e19d0376

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Toshiba AMOBEADs.](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/us/product/amorphous/amobeads.html)  They are kind of like ferrite beads, but specifically designed to replace RC snubbers.  The noise reduction before/after pictures are impressive.
[image: AMOBEAD Before After]